# Is sequence of random variables with expectation tending to infinity but variance tending to positive constant sufficient for almost sure divergence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of random variables, where $\mathrm{E}\left[X_n\right] \to \infty$, but $\mathrm{Var}\left[X_n\right] \to c$, where $0 < c < \infty$. Is such a sequence of random variables with expectation tending to infinity but with bounded variance sufficient to establish **almost sure** divergence of $\left\{X_n\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$?

To make this question more concrete, consider the sequence $\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\mu}_n - \mu_0\right)$, which we can equivalently write as $\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\mu}_n - \mu\right) + \sqrt{n}\left(\mu - \mu_0\right)$, where $\hat{\mu}$ is the sample mean, $\mu$ is the population mean and $\mu_0$ is a null hypothesis about the unknown value of $\mu$. Suppose that the central limit theorem implies that, as $n \to \infty$, $\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\mu}_n - \mu\right) \overset{d}{\to} \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^2\right)$. However, when $\mu_0 < \mu$, the second term, $\sqrt{n}\left(\mu - \mu_0\right) \to \infty$. Adding $\sqrt{n}\left(\mu - \mu_0\right)$ to a random variable that converges in distribution to Normal would presumably impact only the expected value (sending it to $\infty$), but not the variance, which would still limit to $\sigma^2$. Can we then conclude that $\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\mu}_n - \mu_0\right)$ diverges to $\infty$ **almost surely** when $\mu_0 < \mu$? If we can, is there a rigorous way to show this? And, if not, how else might one establish almost sure divergence in this kind of problem?

Thanks so much to all for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

The statement in the title is false.

Let $a_n=\frac {n} {\sqrt {n-1}}$. Let $(X_n)$ be an independent sequence with $X_n=a_n$ with probability $1-\frac  1n$ and $0$ with probability $\frac  1n$. Then $EX_n=\frac {n} {\sqrt {n-1}} (1-\frac 1 n)=\sqrt {n-1} \to \infty$ and $EX_n^{2}=a_n^{2}(1-\frac 1 n)=n$. So $Var (X_n)=1$ for each $n$. But $\sum_n P(X_n=0)=\sum_n \frac 1  n =\infty$.  By Borel Cantelli Lemma we see that $P(\lim \sup \{X_n=0\})=1$  so so $X_n$ does not diverge with probability $1$.

Comment: Thank you @geetha290krm. That is very helpful. What about specifically for $\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\mu} - \mu_0\right)$? I could be wrong, but intuitively it seems straightforward that $\sqrt{n}\left(\hat{\mu} - \mu_0\right)$ would diverge almost surely to $\infty$ when $\mu_0 < \mu$. Is there a way to show this almost sure divergence? Or am I wrong in my intuition?